# How can I combine a py_function inside a map function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, tensorflow2, tf.dataset

I wanted to combine a py_function inside a map function, which took me a day, despite chatGPT's assistance.

Since [resizing an image with tf.image has implementation differences in relate to openCVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497130/inconsistency-between-image-resizing-with-keras-pil-and-tensorflow), I wanted to keep using the optimized tf.Dataset with the .map API, but also combine the opencv.resize API.

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour]. questions need to be questions. if you want to answer your own question, you can do that. please review [ask] and [answer]. in addition to that issue, I can't make heads or tails of your talk about ".map API". all the code in your question doesn't contain any ".map" at all

Comment: 10q for the feedback. I hope the edit I made makes it clearer. Is there anything else that isn't clear enough?

Comment: the format of self-answers should be https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
def resize_with_opencv_ver6(self, image):
    image = image.numpy()
    image = np.squeeze(image)
    target_shape = (self._target_shape[0], self._target_shape[1])
    resized = cv2.resize(image, target_shape, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    resized = tf.expand_dims(resized, axis=-1)

    return resized

def resize_fn(self, image_path, image, label_index):
    im_shape = image.shape
    [image, ] = tf.py_function(self.resize_with_opencv_ver6, [image], [tf.uint8])
    image.set_shape(im_shape)
    return image_path, image, label_index
```

In general, the resize_fn is called from the tensorflow map API

```
dataset = dataset.map(self.resize_fn, num_parallel_calls=self._autotune)
```

A short explanation: The cv2.resize drops the channels dimension for grayscale images so you can also neglect the np.squeeze command and just stay with the tf.expand_dims to return the image as a tensor with the channels dimension. In addition, the image.shape and the image.set_shape just make sure that the channels' dimension is kept, but they aren't mandatory here.

Hope it will help others.